# How do I set desiredCount on ECS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I"m running an EC2 cluster on AWS ECS.

I launch my service like so:

`ecs-cli compose -f docker-compose-base.yml -f docker-compose-prod.yml --ecs-profile root service up --create-log-groups`

In my `ecs-params.yml` file I specified `desiredCount: 2`:

```
version: 1
task_definition:
  services:
    api:
      desiredCount: 2
```

However, it always get a default desired count of 1:

```
INFO[0000] Using ECS task definition                     TaskDefinition="api:5"
WARN[0000] No log groups to create; no containers use 'awslogs'
INFO[0016] (service api) has started 1 tasks: (task decf9405-63b1-4ddf-ba12-69018299e157).  timestamp="2020-05-16 12:03:46 +0000 UTC"
INFO[0077] Service status                                desiredCount=1 runningCount=1 serviceName=api
```

How do I change the default desired count without having to run `service scale N` command?

Comment: Where did you find `desiredCount` parameter? In the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-ecsparams.html) there is no such parameter?

Answer (score 1):

That's right, the default desired count is 1. You'll need to use [ecs-cli compose service scale](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-service-scale.html) This command sets the desired count of the service to the specified count. Here's the full syntax, where n is the desired count:

ecs-cli compose service scale [--deployment-max-percent n] [--deployment-min-healthy-percent n] [--timeout value] n [--help]

And here's an example that sets desired count to 2:

ecs-cli compose --project-name hello-world --file hello-world.yml service scale 2